# What's the simplest mesh file I can produce?

Tags: qt, 3d, blender

I would like to set a mesh file on Qt
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcustom3ditem.html#meshFile-prop. The item in the file must be in Wavefront OBJ format and include vertices, normals, and UVs. It also needs to be in triangles.

What's the simplest mesh file I can produce? By simple I mean one that will be cheap in cpu cycles to process.

Should I use Blender to generate such a file? I did so and got the following:

```
# Blender v2.80 (sub 75) OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
o Cube
v 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
vt 0.625000 0.000000
vt 0.375000 0.250000
vt 0.375000 0.000000
vt 0.625000 0.250000
vt 0.375000 0.500000
vt 0.375000 0.250000
vt 0.625000 0.500000
vt 0.375000 0.750000
vt 0.625000 0.750000
vt 0.375000 1.000000
vt 0.375000 0.500000
vt 0.125000 0.750000
vt 0.125000 0.500000
vt 0.875000 0.500000
vt 0.625000 0.500000
vt 0.625000 0.250000
vt 0.625000 0.750000
vt 0.625000 1.000000
vt 0.375000 0.750000
vt 0.875000 0.750000
vn 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 1.0000
vn -1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 -1.0000 0.0000
vn 1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 -1.0000
s off
f 5/1/1 3/2/1 1/3/1
f 3/4/2 8/5/2 4/6/2
f 7/7/3 6/8/3 8/5/3
f 2/9/4 8/10/4 6/8/4
f 1/11/5 4/12/5 2/13/5
f 5/14/6 2/9/6 6/15/6
f 5/1/1 7/16/1 3/2/1
f 3/4/2 7/7/2 8/5/2
f 7/7/3 5/17/3 6/8/3
f 2/9/4 4/18/4 8/10/4
f 1/11/5 3/19/5 4/12/5
f 5/14/6 1/20/6 2/9/6
```

Comment: `By simple I mean one that will be cheap in cpu cycles to process.` What exactly do you mean by `process`? What are you going to do with that mesh?

Comment: Scale and move around. That answer your question? Sorry I'm new to 3D.

Comment: The cheapest would probably be a single triangle, not that useful though.

Comment: I would like to make my own/custom bars chart (similar to the one shown on https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/q3dbars.html) hopefully faster and so that is possible to have a series with bars with different colors. Perhaps it's useful for that if I scale the tringle accordingly to the size of bar I want. That makes sense?

Comment: You should use a mesh which resembles a bar of a bar chart then.

Comment: Why not a single tringle? Or a plane?

Comment: Because a triangle doesn't look like a bar, neither does a plane.

Comment: If chart scale goes from 0 to 100 at discrete intervals of 1 then 100 bars will be required. Looks like I can have just one mesh file and scale it to 100 different sizes or I can have 100 different mesh files. Which option would be better?

Comment: Scale it to the size you need.

Comment: For different bar sizes color should be different. One way to to do that is by setting a texture image (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcustom3ditem.html#setTextureImage). Would be better to have different mesh files with different colors?